# How to iterate queryset dictionary in django template

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates

This is my dictionary i get from view:

```
{'questions_in_topic': <QuerySet [{'question_id__description': 'Describe your most significant leadership experience'}, {'questi
on_id__description': 'Which kind of leader are you?'}]>}
```

How do I show individual questions in django template?

The view is below:

```
def get_question_from_topic(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        questions_in_topic = QuestionTopic.objects.filter(topic_id=request.GET['topicId']).values('question_id__description').order_by('question_id__description')
        print(questions_in_topic)
        context = { 'questions_in_topic': questions_in_topic }
        print(context)
        return render(request, 'recruiter/add_question_library.html', context)
    return render(request, 'recruiter/add_question_library.html', context)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
{% if questions_in_topic %}
{% for question in questions_in_topic %}
    Question: {{ question }}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: What happens? You have the rest of the template? Please post more details!

Answer (score 1):

If you're only accessing one field from the queryset then using [values_list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list) is probably better for your needs

Changing

```
questions_in_topic = QuestionTopic.objects.filter(topic_id=request.GET['topicId']).values('question_id__description').order_by('question_id__description')
```

To

```
questions_in_topic = QuestionTopic.objects.filter(topic_id=request.GET['topicId']).order_by('question_id__description').values_list('question_id__description', flat=True)
```

After this `questions_in_topic` will be a list of strings. You can then use these in your template like so

```
{% for question in questions_in_topic %}
    Question: {{ question }}
{% empty %}
    There are no questions.
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: its converting queryset into list, but iteration above is not working!

Comment: @SomnathDas What does your template code look like at the moment? What do you mean by not working? What is the error / what do you see in the view?

Comment: I want to see questions list, the code u shared for template is not giving any output: It's going into empty criteria

Comment: View is returning correct dictionary, but not able to show it through template

Comment: What should be happening is that `questions_in_topic` is now a list with the two question strings in it. Is that the case? Also, you say it's not showing any output & is going into the empty criteria - does that mean that it is showing "There are no questions."

Comment: View is returning this: {'questions_in_topic': <QuerySet ['Describe your most significant leadership experience', 'Which kind of leader are you?']>}
But on template, I am seeing "There are no questions"

Comment: It looks like you haven't changed to use `values_list` that you will need to do for my template code to work. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "the view is returning..." do you mean that is what your `context` variable that you pass to the `render` function is set to?